# Ordering a list represented by a String using a Regular Expression in impala

Tags: regex, impala

I have the next String, which represents a list:

```
<i>'3_val1, 1_val2, 8_val3, 5_val2'</i>
```

From it, i would like to obtain:

```
<i>'val2, val1, val2, val3'</i>
```

This order is defined by the prefix number for each val (1-3-5-8 in this case, ascendent order).

What procedure could I follow in order to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: The best you could do is to get them into a hash / pairs with the prefix being the key,  and the value the remainder. Then loop with a counter to create an array. The counter is the key to get the value. You'd firstly extract each one first with a regex `(\d+)_(.+)` where group 1 is the key, and group 2 is the value.

Comment: Yes, i guess i will have to go for the UDF solution to solve this. It is a relatively simple task to do using for example Java, but i was looking for the 'native' alternative in impala, which would need the use of a regexp.